# Python: ImportError with package

Tags: python, python-import

I develop in eclipse using pydev plugin. When I run project in eclipse everything works fine. But when I try to run it from command line I get an Import error. I have a dir structure like this:

```
      TGRParser 
        |----tgr
              |--graph
              |--main
              |   |-- main.py
              |   |-- __init__.py  
              |--parser
                  |--__init__py
                  |--parserClass.py
```

Now I have a class Main in module main (main.py) in package main (TGRParser/tgr/main). Now in class Main I try to call

```
    from tgr.parser.parserClass import Parser
```

It works fine from within eclipse but doesnt work at all from command line. I checked sys.path. They are both the same in cmd line and in eclipse.

It says:

```
 File "main.py", line 6, in <module>
from tgr.parser.parserClass import Parser
ImportError: No module named tgr.parser.parserClass
```

Comment: Do you have \__init__.py files in all of those packages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `TGRParser` directory to your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running this on the command line as

`python main.py`

within the main folder, then you can't use `import tgr...` since tgr is several directories up. It's also impossible to do a relative import while you're running a program within the package, so doing `from .. import parser` won't work.

Your best choice is to move `main.py` into the `TGRParser` folder, alongside the tgr folder. At that point, running `python main.py` should work just fine.

Comment: also an idea - but I will go with the other sulution. Can you point me to any good material about python packages?

Comment: You're certainly welcome to. However, that really isn't how Python packages should be used or designed. A `main.py` file that imports a package should exist outside of the package itself.